# Hibernate in memory DB

Tags: hibernate

I am trying to write unit tests for hibernate DAOs, if I create test-applicationContext with postgres dialect, then do I need to install postgres to run the tests? Is there any better way to do this without having to install DB just to run the test cases?
Thanks

Comment: right now my test-applicationContext is using a tempDB/table in my postgres database for running the unit test, but how do I make it inmemory without the need to install postgres?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html) that can also run as a in-memory database. Check [this blog](http://boplicity.nl/confluence/display/Java/Unit+testing+JPA+-+Hibernate+components+with+in-memory+H2+database) for a quick example.